# Placing proper preposition

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I am seeing a picture and telling someone

at/on the left side you and at/on the right side me

Answer (score 1):

http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/words/describing_pictures.htm

Here you can find some prepostion groups for describing pictures.
Without some real decriptions of pictures such mere lists are rather boring.